# WebRTC communication only using HTTP port 80?

Tags: tcp, webrtc, turn

- When peers are behind different NAT, we use STUN to get things going
- When direct peer-to-peer fails, we turn towards TURN server,
- and when all the UDP ports are blocked in the system, we connect to the TURN server with TCP transport
- but what if all ports except 80 is blocked( peer behind corporate proxy), what then? would the above TURN server still work? or should I get a webrtc gateway and rely upon RTMP as fallback? Any other alternative?

previously, I made a mistake of assuming TCP needs only port 80, but [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/bq2tUi_guE4) makes me doubt things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how blocked is your network. If there is a Proxy which is checking for HTTP header, TURN (STUN) over TCP wont work. But if flows over port 80 aren't checked by a proxy (e.g. Firewall only), TURN over TCP should work.

If your TURN allows to be reached over TLS on port 443, the encrypted layer should bypass the proxy/firewall. In fact the proxy will think that flows are HTTPS request. But if the proxy is able to "break" the SSL layer (MITM e.g. [Burp proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)), it could reject your communications because it wont understand the TURN request as an HTTP one.

Answer (score 0):

443 should be available also. 80 for signaling, 443 for TURN.